# file need to go through a php page using .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, url-rewriting, http-code-500

I'm looking for a way to convert this type of URL:

```
http://www.example.com/dl/F5EGD6
```

Into `http://www.example.com/dl/files/my_file.zip` using a PHP page to request the URL from the DB with `F5EGD6`. I tried ith this htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (*)$ /dl.php [QSA]
```

But it doesn't work. I get Error 500 :(

I don't know how to handle that...

Anyone know?

Comment: You should check out any of the many [mod_rewrite tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mod+rewrite+tutorial#hl=en&safe=off&pwst=1&sa=X&ei=-1HCTMGqDIKdlgedwJQD&ved=0CBcQvwUoAQ&q=mod_rewrite+tutorial&spell=1&fp=4ba096ba63ca8429) out there. They explain how to do this quite well.

Comment: Is h11p a typo? Twice?

Comment: LOL I'm not alowed to put links since I don't have many reputation points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were going to transform

```
http://www.example.com/dl/files/zip.zip
```

into

```
http://www.example.com/dl.php?what=zip.zip
```

I would do something like

```
RewriteRule ^dl/files/(.*)$ dl.php?what=$1
```

That matches `http://www.example.com/dl/files/anythinghereincludingslash/`
and would transform it into
`http://www.example.com/dl.php?what=anythinghereincludingslash/`.

I think that's probably what you're looking for.

N.B. mod_rewrite would need to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# Check if the requested url stats with /dl/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dl/
#if so, redirect everything to dl.php, placing everything in $_GET['url']:
RewriteRule ^dl/files/(.*) /dl.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Requesting `http://www.example.com/dl/files/my_file.zip` will result in calling `dl.php`, where `$_GET['url'] == 'my_file.zip'`. The user will not see this in the urlbar, they'll just keep seeing their original url.

**Safety tip:** It's obvious you have to use a `file_exists()`, but do not forget to check if `../` is in the url. If I where to call `example.com/dl/files/../../index.php`, I'd get your `index.php`, or any other file I want (if I knew your file structure).

Comment: Thanks for the security tips by the way (never too late to upvote ;) )